# Flutter Pie chart with Image Widget

Tags: flutter, charts

I'm Using  fl_chart: ^0.12.2 for add PIE chart in to the my app. But i'm unable to add add image on very section

I want something similar to this

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo is modification of `PieChartSample2` 
official example https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/pie_chart/samples/pie_chart_sample2.dart
You can in `PieChartSectionData` use `badgeWidget` and set `badgePositionPercentageOffset`

```
/// If [badgeWidget] is not null, it draws a widget at the middle of section,
/// by default it draws the widget at the middle of section, but you can change the
/// [badgePositionPercentageOffset] to have your desire design,
/// the value works the same way as [titlePositionPercentageOffset].
```

code snippet

```
List<PieChartSectionData> showingSections() {
    return List.generate(4, (i) {
      ...
      final double widgetSize = isTouched ? 55 : 40;

      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            value: 40,
            title: '40%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/ophthalmology-svgrepo-com.svg',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        case 1:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xfff8b250),
            ...
```

working demo

[image]

full code of modified `PieChartSample2`

```
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'indicator.dart';

class _Badge extends StatelessWidget {
  final String svgAsset;
  final double size;
  final Color borderColor;

  const _Badge(
    this.svgAsset, {
    Key key,
    @required this.size,
    @required this.borderColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: PieChart.defaultDuration,
      width: size,
      height: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: borderColor,
          width: 2,
        ),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
            offset: const Offset(3, 3),
            blurRadius: 3,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(size * .15),
      child: Center(
        child: kIsWeb
            ? Image.network(svgAsset, fit: BoxFit.contain)
            : SvgPicture.asset(
                svgAsset,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PieChartSample2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PieChart2State();
}

class PieChart2State extends State {
  int touchedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1.3,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 18,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 1,
                child: PieChart(
                  PieChartData(
                      pieTouchData:
                          PieTouchData(touchCallback: (pieTouchResponse) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlLongPressEnd ||
                              pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlPanEnd) {
                            touchedIndex = -1;
                          } else {
                            touchedIndex = pieTouchResponse.touchedSectionIndex;
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                      borderData: FlBorderData(
                        show: false,
                      ),
                      sectionsSpace: 0,
                      centerSpaceRadius: 40,
                      sections: showingSections()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xff0293ee),
                  text: 'First',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xfff8b250),
                  text: 'Second',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xff845bef),
                  text: 'Third',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xff13d38e),
                  text: 'Fourth',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 18,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 28,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<PieChartSectionData> showingSections() {
    return List.generate(4, (i) {
      final isTouched = i == touchedIndex;
      final double fontSize = isTouched ? 25 : 16;
      final double radius = isTouched ? 60 : 50;
      final double widgetSize = isTouched ? 55 : 40;

      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            value: 40,
            title: '40%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/ophthalmology-svgrepo-com.svg',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        case 1:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xfff8b250),
            value: 30,
            title: '30%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/ophthalmology-svgrepo-com.svg',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        case 2:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xff845bef),
            value: 15,
            title: '15%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/ophthalmology-svgrepo-com.svg',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        case 3:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xff13d38e),
            value: 15,
            title: '15%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/ophthalmology-svgrepo-com.svg',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        default:
          return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

full code for png

```
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'indicator.dart';

class _Badge extends StatelessWidget {
  final String svgAsset;
  final double size;
  final Color borderColor;

  const _Badge(
    this.svgAsset, {
    Key key,
    @required this.size,
    @required this.borderColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: PieChart.defaultDuration,
      width: size,
      height: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: borderColor,
          width: 2,
        ),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
            offset: const Offset(3, 3),
            blurRadius: 3,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(size * .15),
      child: Center(
        child: kIsWeb
            ? Image.network(svgAsset, fit: BoxFit.contain)
            : Image.asset(svgAsset, fit: BoxFit.contain) /*SvgPicture.asset(
                svgAsset,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              )*/,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PieChartSample2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PieChart2State();
}

class PieChart2State extends State {
  int touchedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1.3,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 18,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 1,
                child: PieChart(
                  PieChartData(
                      pieTouchData:
                          PieTouchData(touchCallback: (pieTouchResponse) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlLongPressEnd ||
                              pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlPanEnd) {
                            touchedIndex = -1;
                          } else {
                            touchedIndex = pieTouchResponse.touchedSectionIndex;
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                      borderData: FlBorderData(
                        show: false,
                      ),
                      sectionsSpace: 0,
                      centerSpaceRadius: 40,
                      sections: showingSections()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xff0293ee),
                  text: 'First',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xfff8b250),
                  text: 'Second',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xff845bef),
                  text: 'Third',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Indicator(
                  color: Color(0xff13d38e),
                  text: 'Fourth',
                  isSquare: true,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 18,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 28,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<PieChartSectionData> showingSections() {
    return List.generate(4, (i) {
      final isTouched = i == touchedIndex;
      final double fontSize = isTouched ? 25 : 16;
      final double radius = isTouched ? 60 : 50;
      final double widgetSize = isTouched ? 55 : 40;

      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            value: 40,
            title: '40%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/test.png',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        case 1:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xfff8b250),
            value: 30,
            title: '30%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/test.png',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        case 2:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xff845bef),
            value: 15,
            title: '15%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/test.png',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        case 3:
          return PieChartSectionData(
            color: const Color(0xff13d38e),
            value: 15,
            title: '15%',
            radius: radius,
            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
            badgeWidget: _Badge(
              'assets/test.png',
              size: widgetSize,
              borderColor: const Color(0xff0293ee),
            ),
            badgePositionPercentageOffset: .50,
          );
        default:
          return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: is it need show .svg file? can't we use .png file for this.

Comment: @ayeshdon, yes , you can change class _Badge, see full code and change SvgPicture.assset to what you need

Comment: Need to reproduce, could you post reproduce code. thanks.

Comment: padding: EdgeInsets.all(size * .15),
      child: Center(
        child: kIsWeb
            ? Image.network(svgAsset, fit: BoxFit.contain)
            : SvgPicture.asset(
                svgAsset,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),

        //     Image.asset(
        //   svgAsset,
        // ),
      ),

Comment: works fine. do not forget to change switch 0, 1, 2, 3 's svg to png

Comment: you can see update full code for png and working demo.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks